# Can I use the Lightning to Micro USB Adapter and connect a keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, ipod-touch, usb, lightning

Can I use Apple's Lightning to Micro USB Adapter with the iPod touch 5th generation to connect a Micro USB keyboard?

Comment: You want to connect a keyboard to your iPod touch ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Lightning to Micro USB adapter will only allow you to use micro USB cables to charge and sync your device.